# Including JSP calls in Call Hierarchy of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, call-hierarchy

How can I get Eclipse Call Hierarchy to support calls in JSP files?

I am an avid user of the Call Hierarchy feature of Eclipse, as it helps me navigate and find all call sources of a method or other entity. But I find that the Call Hierarchy listing completely ignores JSP files in a project, and this makes my coding and debugging difficult. I have to rely on text-search tools to find the calls or (most of the time) simply risk missing them out entirely.

For some reason, the support for JSP in Eclipse is substandard compared that for their Java source code file counterparts, and has not improved. Is this simply not possible at the moment? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Don't use complicated algorithm in JSP, move to pure Java. JSP should be only presentation level (and stack call never occur). IDE has few difficulties, one of reasons is compiling JSP in the fly, temporary code doesn't exist

Comment: @JacekCz haha! Tell that to the idiots I was working with back then. Sometimes the entire business logic was inside JSP. Yuck! **PS:** I agree with you about JSP being presentation only. I don't work with them anymore, so this is an old question. Thanks for your comment.